# Exception Message Handling

Tags: java, exception, logging

Lets assume that we have a class which run the application (lets call it *Main* class) and invoke the business logic class (lets call it *Logic* class). The *Main* class is responsible for communication with the user.

Logic class *throws* some *SpecificException* which is caught by *Main*. This Exception might have *message* plus some *specific* information which might be beneficial.

Lets consider several scenarios.

1. We define *message* and *specificInfomation* fields in *SpecificException*, fill these parameters when this exception is thrown and combine a message for the user in *Main* based on the introduced fields.
2. We define only *message* field in *SpecificException* and build the message together with *specific information* where this exception is thrown. In Main we just print the message.
3. We define *message* and *specificInformation* fields in *SpecificException*, but they are used only to *log* the information in *Main*, the message for the user is build separately.

***Which is the best way out of these three?*** *Or maybe you could provide your own one?*

Comment: The message is for humans to read.  If that is enough, don't use fields.  If you actually _need_ the actual information later, use fields.  In the case of "might be beneficial" don't do it until you have a use case for the values being needed later.

Comment: In this case the question is if we should distinguish users and developers and have separate messages for them.

Comment: Users should never see stack trace messages.  Those are for developers.

Comment: Yes, this is very much clear, but I am talking just about messages which could be inside some exception.

Comment: User messages should almost always be translatable. That means the code holds the message lookup key, not the actual message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you wrote Logic throws the `SpecificException` but some specific information may be available only in `Main` (and if you have different mains the could be semantically different, i.e. they may depend on the context).

So it seems reasonable that `SpecificException` provides only context information that can be provided by `Logic` and then in `Main` you can have a helper class that uses `SpecificException` and specific information to build a user message and (if it's needed) log (on file,db,etc) some informations that could be used later for statitics or something similar.

The helper class may manage different Main/SpecificInformation (may be in `Main` you execute different calls to `Logic` and for each call you may want to provide different `SpecificInformation`). The helper class could also manage more than one Exception class

Comment: Ok, it seems that there was some misunderstanding. The information can be available in Logic - no worries, the question is mostly, how we should deliver it to the Main and if we should separate the messages for developers and users.

Comment: I also don't really see that much of a point to create a separate helper class if I can change this SpecificException behavior, however, maybe it is more beneficial to have a parent exception.

Comment: if you have all the information in logic I prefer to build the user message in Main and manage in the exception the message for the developer.